# React Native Navigation using route resulting in TypeError

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Im getting the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.firstName')`

This is my `handleContinue` function.

```
const handleContinue = () => {
    console.log(firstName)
    navigation.navigate('Conditions', {
        screen: 'FinishScreen',
        params: {
            firstName: firstName
        }
    });
```

Here is my `app.js`

```
import DriverInputs from './screens/DriverInputs';
import Questionnaire from './screens/Questionnaire';
import Conditions from './screens/Conditions';
import NoInductionNoEntry from './screens/NoInductionNoEntry';
import DockSafetyPractices from './screens/DockSafetyPractices'
import SafetyOnSite from './screens/SafetyOnSite';
import ItsColdInHere from './screens/ItsColdInHere';
import AlertsStandards from './screens/AlertsStandards';
import WantToKnowMore from './screens/WantToKnowMore';
import TimeForInductionQuiz from './screens/TimeForInductionQuiz';
import FinishScreen from './screens/FinishScreen';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={
                {headerShown: false}
            }>
                <Stack.Screen name='DriverInputs'
                    component={DriverInputs}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='FinishScreen'
                    component={FinishScreen}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='Conditions'
                    component={Conditions}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='NoInductionNoEntry'
                    component={NoInductionNoEntry}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='DockSafetyPractices'
                    component={DockSafetyPractices}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='SafetyOnSite'
                    component={SafetyOnSite}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='ItsColdInHere'
                    component={ItsColdInHere}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='AlertsStandards'
                    component={AlertsStandards}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='WantToKnowMore'
                    component={WantToKnowMore}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='TimeForInductionQuiz'
                    component={TimeForInductionQuiz}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='Questionnaire'
                    component={Questionnaire}/>


            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>


    );
}
```

My objective is to pass the paramaters from my `handleContinue` function to `FinishScreen`, whilst navigating to the 'Conditions' screen.

Referencing https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params, section `Passing params to nested navigators` is what I believe I have implemented but the error persists.

This is my `onPress` function in 'Conditions' screen

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FinishScreen")}
```

It is when I reach FinishScreen in my emulator that the error occurs.

```
This error is located at:
    in FinishScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
    in MaybeFreeze (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.firstName')
```

Also, `FinishScreen`

```
const FinishScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
    console.log(route.params)

    const {firstName} = route.params;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>FinishScreen{
                {firstName}
            }</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default FinishScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to save users' data globally and then retrieve it from their example redux or context API. If not possible then you have to pass data in nested screens first.

```
  onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate('FinishScreen', {firstName: firstName})
            }
```